# Getting data between dates from postgres database in R

Tags: r, postgresql

I wrote an SQL Query for getting data between two dates. It is working in java but it is giving errors in R

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
>   RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  operator does not exist: date >= integer
>   LINE 1: ..._id,visit_date from customer_tb  where visit_date between 20...
>   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.)

Comment: Do you mean you want data between say '2015-05-01' and '2015-04-01'?

If yes then,
`select * from conn where timestamp >= '2015-04-01' and timestamp <= '2015-05-01';`

Comment: It might be useful if you post the code you're asking about.

Comment: Do post the actual query, but I would guess you might be missing quotes. Are you doing `visit_date between 2015-05-01` or something?